# Is there a way in Heroku to connect to a remote MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, heroku

Heroku supports no database other than PostgreSQL, but my question is here regarding remote database. Can a Heroku instance running Rails connect to a remote database connection? To be more specific, the remote database connection of MySQL resides at Amazon RDS.

If it's not possible at all, can I use remote database through HTTP requests generated by Rails code?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a Heroku instance running Rails connect to a remote database
>   connection?

Yes

> To be more specific, the remote database connection of MySQL resides
>   at Amazon RDS.

Yes. See:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-database-provisioning
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds#configuring-a-heroku-ruby-app-to-use-a-mysql-rds-instance

> You must grant Heroku dynos access to your RDS instance. The recommended way to do this is to configure the RDS instance to only accept SSL-encrypted connections from authorized users and configure the security group for your instance to permit ingress from all IPs, eg 0.0.0.0/0.